# why is my program skipping scanf()?

Tags: c

Part of my assignment is to get user input; then, if the input is incorrect, prompt them to try again. When I use `if` statements and `while` loops in this way, they completely skip over the `scanf` command, and the program either runs infinitely or terminates immediately, skipping over the second chance for user input.  Any idea how to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number;
    printf("please insert positive number\n");
    scanf(" %d", &number);
    // if the user inputs a value that is not a positive integer, it becomes false
    // i want the if statement to re-prompt them to input the correct value
    if (number <= 0)
    {
        printf("try again\n");
        scanf(" %d", &number);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. See http://ideone.com/Hhszou Try to add `printf("%d\n",  number);` after `scanf`. Also test the return value of `scanf`, i.e. `if (1 != scanf(....)) { printf("scanf error\n"};`

Comment: You aren't checking whether `scanf()` succeeds, or reading off bad characters if it doesn't.  And, there's no `while` loop in the code shown and no way it "runs infinitely" (aside from waiting for input, maybe).

Comment: i compiled it and it works as it is. If  I enter a number lower or equal zero it asks me another time for a number.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` Returns the number of fields successfully converted and assigned; the return value does not include fields that were read but not assigned. A return value of 0 indicates that no fields were assigned.

The scanf function reads data from the standard input stream stdin and writes the data into the location given by argument. Each argument must be a pointer to a variable of a type that corresponds to a type specifier in format.

I recommend **handle errors** . it will happen in Real World code. (write Concise and robust Code).

so i recommend something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int read_positive_int(int *n){
    int retry = 3;
    do{
        printf("Please enter a positive number:\n");
        if (scanf("%d", n) == 1){
            if (*n > 0) return 1; //ok
        }    
    } while (--retry);
    return 0; //error
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    if (read_positive_int(&n))
        printf("n = %d\n", n);
    else 
        printf("error\n");
}
```

i hope this helps.

Comment: your code is ok - with some error handling, pointers, functions and so on, but considering the programming level of the questioner, I'm not sure if this answer would be helpful for him

Comment: `scanf()` also leaves bad input in the input stream... so you need to read those characters through other means if `scanf()` fails, before trying again.  As is, if you enter 'q' (for example) the first time, `scanf()` will immediately fail on all the retries too because 'q' will be the next character in the stream every time.

Comment: in that case using getchar() may helps, see: http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Answer (score 0):

the code does what it's written to do, so in your case it's following:

1. message to user: enter a positive number
2. scanf: reads user's input
3. determine, if the number is positive

   - if yes - the *if* body will not be executed 
     and program **ends**
   - if not - print a message, read a number and program **ends**

the thing you are looking for is a **loop**

you want to do something like this:

```
while the entered number is not positive, ask the user to enter the number again
```

that's what loops are used for

```
int number;

printf("please insert positive number\n");

scanf("%d", &number);

while (number <= 0) {
    printf("try again\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);
}

return 0;
```

Comment: You need to read the bad input some other way when `scanf()` fails, or that bad input will remain in the input stream and cause `scanf()` to fail next time as well.  Check `scanf()`'s return to see if it assigned the field, if not read the bad characters with `getchar()` in a loop or something, then retry the `scanf()`.